# How should I store raw steaks in the freezer?

Tags: freezing, steak

What's the best method for storing steaks in the freezer? How should I wrap them? Should they be stored individually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, store them individually.

First, wrap them *tightly* in plastic wrap, preferably one that says it's specifically for freezer use. Then wrap this tightly in aluminum foil. They'll keep for months without freezer burn this way.

Comment: +1 for plastic wrap AND foil.  Don't forget to put labels on them so you can quickly see which steak was bought at what time.

Comment: Why the foil?  Just to protect the plastic wrap?

Comment: @sdg: I think so. Plastic wrap is rather delicate to be tossing around a freezer. Aluminum also provides another layer of protection from freezer burn.

Answer (score 5):

Vacuum-sealed in plastic bags works really well. You can put multiple in each bag as long as the vacuum sealer can get all the air out.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that a frost free (refrigerator) freezer is not a good place to store anything, and in particular, meat.

In general, I keep food that I intend to use soon upstairs in the fridge freezer for convenience, but If I'm storing it for a week or more, It goes down in the basement deep freeze.

A frost free freezer keeps warming up to melt the ice, giving very inconsistent temperatures. and can even lead to partial thawing of the surfaces of meat.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap well in plastic (individually) and then put in a freezer bag. We can get 6 months easy. Possibly more but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 3):

I wrap steaks individually in freezer paper, then put them into ziploc freezer bags. The freezer paper is really nice because it doesn't stick to the meat.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put them in a ziplock type bag and suck as much air as possible (water bath method or use a vacuum machine)
2. Freeze the steaks **as quickly as possible**. Set them in a single layer on a baking sheet and put them in the freezer.
3. Once frozen, wrap in foil to protect them further (as other wrote).